# Run compiled/production javascript code of GWT maven project in Eclipse (through Jetty DevMode server)

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt

I am trying to run GWT compiled/production javascript code from inside Eclipse for a project generated through the gwt-maven-plugin. Each time I launch a run/debug configuration (which points to the target/MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT folder) through the Google plugin , the DevMode server mercilessly wipes out my compiled javascripts, and start to run things in dev mode, end-result being that if I remove the gwt.codesvr parameter from the URL, I get the dreaded "GWT module 'MyModuleName' may need to be (re)compiled".

How can I run my compiled/production javascript code through the DevMode server inside Eclipse ?

The aim being: 
1) to confirm that the prod javascript code behaves the same in dev mode 
2) to be still able to debug the server side java code if I want

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback and your expertise.

Regards

kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known regression of GWT 2.7, but it's not clear yet whether it'll be fixed or not: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=9021

To debug your server-side code, use "Debug As… → Maven…" and use the jetty-maven-plugin or some tomcat?-maven-plugin, e.g. using the `jetty:run-exploded` goal.
Or use [M2Eclipse Webby](https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-webby) or the M2Eclipse WTP integration (in other words: do what you'd do for any other Maven-based Web project, as you want to put GWT out of the equation and only use the output of its compiler)